# Remove spaces from selected state in option dropdown on change event

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, spaces, selected

In a data query, I get a tree structure:

```
<select name="parent" id="select_parent">
<option> >Administrator </option>
<option> &nbsp;>Manager </option>
<option> &nbsp;&nbsp;>Sales </option>
<option> &nbsp;&nbsp;>Operator </option>
<option> &nbsp;>Promoter </option>
</select>
```

Obviously this looks good on the combobox options, But when I select a value ... this is shown complete with spaces. What I want is to remove spaces when it is only a selected value.

I tried this:

```
$('#select_parent').bind("change",function()
{
    var s = $('#select_parent option:selected').html();
    $('#select_parent option:selected').html(s.replace(/&nbsp;/g, ''));
});
```

But after eliminating the spaces ... they will return to see if the item no longer has the selected attribute?

Comment: So you're manually indenting your `select`'s options? There should be an easier way to do that.

Comment: Don't indent with spaces, use [`optgroup`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_optgroup.asp)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you'd like to display the selected list item still with the spacing while removing the spacing only in the select's displayed text, you can try this hack:

```
$('#select_parent').bind("change", function() {
    var space_offset = 8;
    var matches = $('#select_parent option:selected').text().match(/\s+?/g);
    var n_spaces = (matches) ? matches.length : 0;
    $(this).css('text-indent', -(n_spaces*space_offset));
});
```

The `select`'s text property is immutable, therefore I made a small css hack to un-indent the selected option's text inside the `select`'s display based on how many spaces it has.

[***JSFiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/RvQfH/6/)

Don't forget to remove any extra spacing besides `&nbsp;` insde your `option`s' texts and adjust the `space_offset` to match the width of a space character in pixels, if your page uses a different font or font size.

**edit:** I tested it on Chrome only, for Firefox it'd require extra css hacking.

**edit:** Alright, here's my final version without any css hack:

```
var trig = ($.browser.mozilla) ? 'click' : 'mousedown';
$(function() {
    $('#select_parent').on("change", function() {
        var sel = $('#select_parent option:selected');
        $(this).data('cur_val', sel);
        var display = sel.clone();
        display.text($.trim(display.text()));
        sel.replaceWith(display);
        $(this).prop('selectedIndex', display.index());
    }).on(trig, function() {
        if ($(this).prop('selectedIndex') == 0)
            return;
        var sel = $('#select_parent option:selected');
        sel.replaceWith($('#select_parent').data('cur_val'));
        $(this).prop('selectedIndex', 0);
    });
    $('#select_parent').change();
});
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/UhwAG/2/)

Tested on Firefox, Chrome, IE and Opera. Should work on Safari as well, as it is Webkit-based.

Comment: +1 for the hack attempt. The arrows `>` now seem like of different size though and the solution might not work in come sophisticated browsers. However, it may look better than nothing :)

Comment: Yes, I just realized text-ident doesn't behave the same for `select`s in firefox as chrome :( Maybe adding some more css hacks. I'll experiment a bit. =]

Comment: BTW, if you use monospace font with fixed width of 8 it will look better: http://jsfiddle.net/RvQfH/2/ (for presentation as least `:)`).

Comment: Oh nicely done, I was just experimenting with fonts too. It still looks bad on firefox (due to the select's behavior), I'm not very good with CSS but I'll experiment a bit later. =]

Comment: edited the answer to add a fixed version for options without spacing (was returning an error), I didn't edit it earlier because I was trying to fix the behavior cross-browser but it doesn't seem like an easy task atm. :P

Comment: Yes, it doesn't look very good on firefox. If you want to add advanced styling to your `select`'s, you could use a plugin such as http://dellsala.com/269/combo-box-input-element-jquery-plugin/

Comment: Yeah, I can check if there isn't an easier way to keep consistency crossbrowser, but most likely it'd require even more "dirty hacks" as Vision commented.

Comment: @csotelo I don't like leaving things unfinished, so I just submitted a definite cross-browser answer. :P The only drawback is that I had to make it switch to the first option every time you open the select, as it's impossible to modify the option's text in the list which is being displayed without modifying the select's display text. I guess that's an affordable price for not using 3rd-party software. Take a look at the new edit/fiddle when you have time. =]

Comment: jajaja is a great solution with jQuery. Although it is strange that it moves to the first option to deploy the list ... I guess that's the key to not affect the other options, but basically you solved my question. I give you the check for the effort. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks, yes, it moves to the first option because I'm changing the selected option's text back to the text with spacing as soon as you open the list, without moving to the first option it'd look a little weird having the selected option's text changing whenever you click it. =]

Comment: Thanks, it working fine in all browsers, but only I.E V 11 it not working it just showing default option plz tell me solution asap.

Answer (score 2):

That looks strange though, but I think this is exactly what you want. You can save the initial values (with spaces) to data of each option, and use the stored value to return the default value back.

```
$("#select_parent"​​).on("change", function() {
    $(this).children().text(function(i, value) {
        if (this.selected) return $.trim(value);
        return $(this).data("def_value");
    });
}).children().each(function() {
    $(this).data("def_value", $(this).text());
});​​​​​​​
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/BkW9h/

Comment: Exactly the same solution I've thought, looks a little awful but can't be done much better without some styling and workarounds. +1

Comment: If it is fine, the only bad thing is that once selected, the label option also remains the same until you select another option. I guess this must be the only way to solve this. thanks

Comment: @FabrícioMatté Yup, I have no better options in mind. To make it look better will engage couple of dirty hacks that won't solve all the problems entirely. Experimenting with DDL events is the last thing I would do.

Answer (score 1):

I think this will be help you.

```js
$(function() {
    $('#select_parent').on("change", function() {
        var sel = $('#select_parent option:selected');
        var display = sel.clone();
        $(".dummy-label").text($.trim(display.text()));   
    });   
    $('#select_parent').change();
});
```

```css
.dummy-label {
  position:absolute;
  background : #fff;
  width : 125px;
  height:16px;
  top:9px;
  left:10px;
  pointer-events: none
}
select {
  width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="dummy-label"></span>
<select name="parent" id="select_parent">
<option selected="selected">Select an option</option>
<option>Administrator</option>
<option>&nbsp;Manager</option>
<option >&nbsp;&nbsp;Sales</option>
<option>&nbsp;&nbsp;Operator</option>
<option>&nbsp;Promoter</option>
</select>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Z48wF/688/

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited short-term help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its long-term value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this and found this will work with latest jquery.

```js
isFirefox = typeof InstallTrigger !== 'undefined';
    var trig = (isFirefox) ? 'click' : 'mousedown';
    $(function() {
      $('#select_parent').on("change", function() {
       var sel = $('#select_parent option:selected');
       $(this).data('cur_val', sel);
       var display = sel.clone();
       display.text($.trim(display.text()));
       sel.replaceWith(display);
       $(this).prop('selectedIndex', display.index());
      }).on(trig, function() {
       if ($(this).prop('selectedIndex') == 0)
        return;
       var sel = $('#select_parent option:selected');
       sel.replaceWith($('#select_parent').data('cur_val'));
       $(this).prop('selectedIndex', 0);
      });
      $('#select_parent').change();
     });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="parent" id="select_parent">
<option selected="selected">Select an option</option>
<option>>Administrator</option>
<option>&nbsp;>Manager</option>
<option>&nbsp;&nbsp;>Sales</option>
<option>&nbsp;&nbsp;>Operator</option>
<option>&nbsp;>Promoter</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's a quick solution for Mozilla Firefox:

`<option style='padding-left:<?=$level*10?>px'>option</option>`

This article [Indenting HTML  options](http://blog.christopherschultz.net/index.php/2009/02/10/indenting-html-select-options/) offers an extensive overview of the options. 
Conclusion: Looks like using `&nbsp;` is the best solution for all browsers, using CSS styling will enhance the display for certain browsers but not interfere with others.